# How to exclude a Laravel folder from a TailwindCSS plugin's global styles

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am working on a Laravel **TailwindCSS** project where the app is already using the famous starter-kit `laravel/breeze` package. `laravel/breeze` is based on **TailwindCSS** for the styling so it comes shipped with **TailwindCSS** and its plugin `tailwindcss/forms`.

`laravel/breeze` then creates its own blade components for the ui scaffolding which utilizes the **TailwindCSS** with its `tailwindcss/forms` plugin. And I have been reusing those already-defined components when building my app to keep the UI consistent, besides creating my own blade components when needed.

However lately I decided I may use general already-defined blade and **TailwindCSS** components after discovering this package called [**BladewindUI**](https://bladewindui.com/).

The problem is that after installing the **BladewindUI** package, some of its components like **Toggle** for example get some of their styles overridden by the `tailwindcss/forms` plugin's styles so they don't look the way they should.

I can't change the plugin's strategy in the plugins option in `tailwind.config.js` from `base` to `class` since it is already used by the breeze blade components and affects other components I have created or even used by other packages.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
plugins: [
  require("@tailwindcss/forms")({
    strategy: 'base', // only generate global styles
    strategy: 'class', // only generate classes
  }),
],
```

I tried excluding the **BladewindUI**'s `vendor` folder from the `content` option in the `tailwind.config.js` by preceding its path with a `"!"` but some of its styles still get overridden by the `tailwindcss/forms` plugin.

```js
//tailwind.config.js

content: [
    '!./vendor/mkocansey/bladewind/resources/views/components/*.blade.php',
    '!./vendor/mkocansey/bladewind/resources/assets/css/*.css',
    '!./vendor/mkocansey/bladewind/public/css/*.css',
    '!./vendor/mkocansey/bladewind/public/css/*.min.css',
    '!./vendor/mkocansey/bladewind/public/js/*.js',

    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
],
```

So my question is simple:
How to isolate the BladewindUI components folder from getting affected by the app's TailwindCSS V3 configuration?

Comment: Try to put bladewind CSS after your app CSS

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka I did try putting bladewind CSS after my app's CSS but that didn't change anything